# I want to install Nvidia Tacotron2 on Windows 10 but the instructions are confusing

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, voice

Can someone explain to me how to install an Nvidia Tacotron2 on Windows 10? Whatever I've done isn't working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What part of the instructions is confusing?

1-Download and extract the LJ Speech dataset

2-Clone this repo: git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2.git

3-CD into this repo: cd tacotron2

4-Initialize submodule: git submodule init; git submodule update

5-Update .wav paths: sed -i -- 's,DUMMY,ljs_dataset_folder/wavs,g' filelists/*.txt
Alternatively, set load_mel_from_disk=True in hparams.py and update mel-spectrogram paths

6-Install PyTorch 1.0

7-Install Apex

8-Install python requirements or build docker image

9-Install python requirements: pip install -r requirements.txt / Install python requirements: pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: 1 , 5 , 7 , 9. Where do I put the LJ Speech dataset?I don't understand how to apply the 5th instruction. I don't understand how to install Apex. In the 8th application, I have to manually enter the pip install commands one by one because some of the versions in the requirements.txt do not match. In a tutorial I followed, the person giving the instructions also showed the waveglow implementation, but I couldn't get it to work in the Jupiter interface. Every line was full of errors.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7gJAEIweSE Here is the link of the tutorial. I'll open a detailed thread tomorrow.

Comment: You would put the dataset wherever you'd like, because in step 5, you replace the text that says DUMMY in each .txt file in the _filelists_ folder with the path to your dataset. (When the argument for "sed" starts with s, as in 's,DUMMY...', it **s**ubstitutes text---in this case, **g**lobally, so not just the first result.) @step 8/9: Using a virtual environment (look up "python venv tutorial") might let you install different module versions without conflicts/mismatches.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it is important. When you state Windows 10, do you mean you are working strictly in Windows? Or in Windows Subsystem for Linux? You will find some [discussion about requirements.txt](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2/issues/366) on the Issues tab of that repository. Lastly, the repo hasn't been updated in two years, and there are no strong active forks, so you probably won't get support from the maintainer.

Comment: I am using windows. I solved all the other problems. I just get an error about Mel Spectrogram screens. I guess I'll have to make changes to a Matplotlib file. And the error I get is this "ValueError: 'bottom' is not a valid value for origin; supported values ​​are 'upper', 'lower'". I found out that my matplotlib version is 3.5.1. If I fix this problem too I will make a backup of my files and directories.